# Prevent whitespaces between two XSLT-elements from being removed by the xslt-processor

Tags: xslt, whitespace

my question is a bit different from the other ones..

i got an xsl-code like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="..."/>    <xsl:value-of select="...">
```

what i want in my result is:

```
result_of_select_1    result_of_select_2
```

what i get is:

```
result_of_select_1result_of_select_2
```

how can i prevent this? ( any xsl:output option for example? )

All the other solutions i found were specificly for the same problem but in the XML-Source document and not in the XSLT-document like this one...

btw. a solution like "insert  elements instead of the spaces" is not a possible solution for my, because the xslt-code is generated dynamically

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white space as you have it is insignificant and gets discarded. If that was not the case, *every last bit* of white space you have in your XSLT code would end up in the result document. You must be explicit about the white space you want in the result.

User either:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(..., '    ', ...)" />
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="..." />
<xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="..." />
```

Comment: Tomalak, its not a good idea to use space anywhere in the xslt if you want to o/p space. Instead you should use either &#32; or <xsl:text>&#32;</xsl:text>

Comment: Why would that be better? The escaped ('&#32;') and the literal form (' ') of the space character are absolutely equivalent. The escaped form is just a lot more typing and clutters up the source code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="..."/><xsl:text>&#32;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="...">
```

EDIT:

Refer to this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for other symbols

Comment: This isn't going to work because the entity will be converted to a space when the xml for the stylesheet is parsed. At which point it will become insignificant whitespace in the same way as the xslt in the original query.

Comment: I disagree ... I have been using this throughout the application without any problem. <xsl:value-of select="'abc'"/>    <xsl:value-of select="'abc'"> will o/p 'abcabc' But, <xsl:value-of select="'abc'"/>&£32;<xsl:value-of select="'abc'"> will output 'abc abc'

Comment: I agree with Ms.Rashmi Pandit's answer .. +1